# what is meant by dependencies in merge module?

Tags: windows, merge-module

what is meant by dependencies in merge module?

Answer (score 1):

Other merge modules. For example MS provides mms of VC runtimes, and some other MSMs can depend on those. They are pulled into your msi automatically (so you include one merge module, and install shield, or whatever msi builder you use, includes its dependencies as well).

There is a special table (optional) with signatures of dependency MSMs. Forgot what it was called, but if you open mm in orca it will be fairly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

[Merge Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369820%28VS.85%29.aspx) are parts of installer software.  Sounds like you are missing some parts of your installer.